# why are my css cards at different positional heights

Tags: css, sass

I am currently working on a weather app and im trying to figure out why my cards have varying positional heights. I am assuming that its because of the amount of lines each of the summaries have but how do I fix this? Thank you.

```
#card__days {

    .card__daily {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        height: 250px;
        width: 185px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        box-shadow: $shadow;
        margin: 0 5px;
        h2 {
            font-size: 2rem;
            padding-top: 10px;
            color: $weather-primary;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 1rem;
            padding: 10px 5px;
        }

        .icon {
            width: 150px;
        }
    }
}
```

[Image of the cards](http://prntscr.com/mfvypc)

Comment: Are you able to recreate this situation using stackoverflow's sample code? I don't see anything in particular but maybe moving to flex box instead of using inline block may be a workaround at least.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it was by making it a display flex and aligning them with a stretch.

```
#card__days {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```